# Custom function with variable arguments implementation using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-custom-function

I have come across custom functions in Google apps script. It involves writing a function which return value after process.

How do I write the below IFS function using apps script

```
function ifs(args)
{
????
}
```

I now want to understand how the variable argumnets enabled custom functions to be created?

For example the ifs function takes variable number of arguments

> IFS function
> Evaluates multiple conditions and returns a value that corresponds to the first true condition.
>
> Sample Usage
> `IFS(A1>90, "A", A1>80, "B", A1>70, "C")`
>
> `IFS({A1:A5} > 3, "bigger", {A1:A5} = 3, "equal")`
>
> Syntax
> `IFS(condition1, value1, [condition2, value2, …])`
>
> condition1 - The first condition to be evaluated. This can be a boolean, a number, an array, or a reference to any of those.
>
> value1 - The returned value if condition1 is TRUE.
>
> condition2, value2, … - Additional conditions and values if the first one is evaluated to be false.

Answer (score 1):

Use [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
function DOUBLE(...input) {
  return input.map(arg => arg * 2);
}
console.log(DOUBLE(5,10,15))
console.log(DOUBLE(1, -1, 0.5))
```

For a custom ifs, try

```js
const customIFS = (...args) => {
 for (let i = 0; i < args.length; ++i){
    if (i % 2 === 0 && typeof args[i] === "boolean" && args[i]) return args[i+1];
 }
}
console.log(customIFS(1>2, "A", 2>1,"B"));
const big = 10, test=1000;
console.log(customIFS(big>test, "less",test===big," equal to big", test>big,"Bigger than big"))
```

Comment: I dont need a DOUBLE function to be written, I want the IFS function to be implemented not DOUBLE

Comment: @CodeGuy Let me know if the latest code works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> I now want to understand how the variable argumnets (sic) enabled custom functions to be created?

Short answer:

Use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Extended answer:

Google Sheets custom function doesn't work exactly as built-in functions like IFS. I.E. when writing a function, a *function pop-up help* might be shown like this

[image]

To create a custom function pop-up help we could use [JSDOC](https://jsdoc.app/)

[image]

While JSDOC syntax has a way to set optional parameters, they are not shown on the custom function pop-up help, but it's possible to get all the custom function arguments by using the arguments object.